# Special Characters in MySQL Query on C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

One of my names in my data looks like this
O'Neil

When I am putting this into my MySQL Query it looks like this
'O'Neil'
Unfortunately it reads the ' between the O and causes an error. I Don't want to replace the ', I still want the name to be O'Neil. Can anyone recommend a way to do this?

I'm using C# (.Net).

Thanks.

CM888.

Answer (score 3):

You should use parameterized queries.Answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c) post are examples of parameterized queries.Indirectly you are performing sql Injection. parameterized queries avoids sql injection and moreover it is a good practice too.

Comment: Cheers; So I add mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", User.name); ?

Answer (score 3):

Jose is right - you should *absolutely* use parameterized queries.

This avoids:

- SQL injection attacks
- Invalid SQL due to quotes etc
- Issues with date/time and numeric formats

It's also just a generally good idea to separate code from data.

See [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Use the SQL escape character ''.

```
'O''Neil'
```

ref : http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries

Comment: No, don't try to fix the SQL - move the data out of the SQL in the first place.