# How can i convert a string of characters into binary string and back again?

Tags: c#, encoding

I need to convert a string into it's binary equivilent and keep it in a string. Then return it back into it's ASCII equivalent.

Comment: What do you consider a binary equivalent of a string?

Comment: Strings aren't designed to store binary data; do you mean you want to encode the string into a series of bytes (or a stream) instead?

Comment: For example if I have string value = "hello"; I need string Binvalue = "0100100001100101011011000110110001101111";

Comment: Yeah, that's a string all right. Now what is "binary string" of it? Do you mean an array of bytes that represents it, as @Cameron said? If so, then you need to choose an encoding. For example, if UTF-8, then `new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("hello")`, IIRC.

Comment: Ah. I see. Next time it would be better if you wrote that in the first place. Also, if this is homework (and it smells like it), please tag it as such.

Comment: Lol it's not, for a little project

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can encode a string into a byte-wise representation by using an [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), e.g. UTF-8:

```
var str = "Out of cheese error";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

To get back a .NET string object:

```
var strAgain = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
// str == strAgain
```

You seem to want the representation as a series of `'1'` and `'0'` characters; I'm not sure why you do, but that's possible too:

```
var binStr = string.Join("", bytes.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2)));
```

Encodings take an abstract string (in the sense that they're an opaque representation of a series of Unicode code points), and map them into a concrete series of bytes. The bytes are meaningless (again, because they're opaque) without the encoding. But, with the encoding, they can be turned back into a string.

You seem to be mixing up "ASCII" with strings; ASCII is simply an *encoding* that deals only with code-points up to 128. If you have a string containing an `'é'`, for example, it has no ASCII representation, and so most definitely cannot be represented using a series of ASCII bytes, even though it can exist peacefully in a .NET `string` object.

See [this article by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for further reading.

Comment: +1 for out of cheese error. That's definitely a serious problem in my book. ;-)

Comment: @Judah: Thanks :D I borrowed it from a book by Terry Pratchett. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(Discworld)).

Comment: What the end result is trying to do is convert a file for a 3d model and upload it to a MYSQL database. However the file has alot of single quotes and double quotes that mess up the query, So my thought was convert it into a byte array and upload it. I got the code working for a byte array but it is terribly slow. Is there another way to upload to a database with the file having ' and " ?

Comment: @David: Yes! Escape your database input (see the [tale of Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)) using [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/652999/21475). Alternatively, consider using [Base64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) -- but still sanitize your input! If it's the actual uploading causing issues, well, that should be encoded properly too (how to do so depends on how it's being uploaded, but there's guaranteed to be a way). Actually, since you want to upload a file, you don't need to actually *parse* it, just use streams instead (e.g. using `File.Open`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use these functions for converting to binary and restore it back :

```
public static string BinaryToString(string data)
{
    List<Byte> byteList = new List<Byte>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 8)
    {
        byteList.Add(Convert.ToByte(data.Substring(i, 8), 2));
    }
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteList.ToArray());
}
```

and for converting string to binary :

```
public static string StringToBinary(string data)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char c in data.ToCharArray())
    {
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Hope Helps You.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the string into bytes, as described in my comment and in Cameron's answer; then iterate, convert each byte into an 8-digit binary number (possibly with `Convert.ToString`, padding appropriately), then concatenate. For the reverse direction, split by 8 characters, run through `Convert.ToInt16`, build up a byte array, then convert back to a string with `GetString`.