# "The given key was not present in the dictionary" when Execute the mysqldatareader in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have run the command without any error in mysql. my other command run fine but this code is not work. do someone know what happen with this code.

```
 private static User GetUser(MySqlCommand cmd)
        {
            User usr = new User();

            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    usr.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                    usr.Level = (Level)Enum.Parse(typeof(Level), rdr["level"].ToString());
                    usr.Email = rdr["email"].ToString();
                    usr.CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["createdDate"].ToString());
                    usr.LastLoginDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["lastLoginDate"].ToString());
                }
            }

           return usr;
        }

 public static User GetUserFromID(int userID)
        {
            string qry = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID = ?userID";

            User user = new User();
            MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(Globals.CONNSTRING);
            cnn.Open();

            using (cnn)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(qry, cnn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userID", userID);

                user = GetUser(cmd);

            }
            cnn.Close();
            return user;
        }
```

The code I paste here gave me error that

> *"The given key was not present in the dictionary."*

on the line of Line 158:

```
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Do someone know what wrong happen with this code? I have added `CharSet=utf8;` in connectionstring as people suggest in SO.

The database I use is mariaDB and connector is mysql latest connector. Do someone know if this have any trouble.

I have no problem while I run my other function. The problem happen in this single function where I use mysqldatareader execution.

Comment: @DGibbs thanks but I am confused. My other query work fine written in C#. I have set utf-8 as people tell in their answer. Now I have check that paramter is set in right way. I thing I am missing something. Can you check it :)

Comment: What is the `Globals.connString` ? What is the value of `cnn` ? Are you sure your connection string is right?

Comment: @SonerGönül yes, it's work on other function that I have written and they call from mysqlhelper. this single function written mysqlexecutereader make trouble. Well, i only have write 1 function who i posted here.

Comment: @user2126670: Please publish your connectionstring, and total exception incl. the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@` instead of `?`:

So:

```
string qry = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID = @userID";
```

and

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", userID);
```

As explained at the pages of MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html#connector-net-tutorials-parameters

Comment: +1 for help, Please tell me the reason behind the answer, I am using Mysql and I am sure ? should work. Refer me to article who do your given code'way

Comment: I got my answer from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp

Comment: @Martin Any idea why StackOverflow doesn't require a string against downvotes, so that they could then be metamoderated away if the reason given is wrong?

Comment: @Poldie: True, it is not required, but sometimes very helpfull for the people who answer (who made a mistake) and people who read the answer (and are about to copy the mistake).

Comment: @user2126670: My answer is backed up by the pages of MySQL itself: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html#connector-net-tutorials-parameters

Comment: @MartinMulder I have tried this trick but its' not work. Thanks for help. I not downvote your answer +1.

Answer (score 1):

You would use @ instead of ? as you are calling a parameter from sql which should be called in sql as:
@userID (whatever type it is, VARCHAR, INT etc)

So your sql proc should look like this

```
Select *
From (TableName)
Where userID = @UserID
```

So in your form you would call @UserID as that is the parameter you passed in sql.

Comment: I tried both way but none of them worked in case of executereader on mysql. still have same issue.

Comment: Did you call the @userID above the code I provided you? Look for type errors ins your work, perhaps you are calling a parameter with a capital letter somewhere when it should be a lower case.

Comment: i tried it but not got it work. I thing cmd.parameter.addwithvalue com with exception if this will have anything wrong.