# How to use input from a textbox and use it in a mysql query in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Code:

```
string connString = "SERVER=;UID=;PASSWORD=;DATABASE=;";
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connString);
MySqlCommand myCommand = connect.CreateCommand();

string input = textBox4.Text;

myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM project WHERE Id = @input";
connect.Open();

MySqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
   textBox1.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();

connect.Close();
```

I am trying to use data from a form textbox (textBox4) and pass that input into a mysql query.

The program works by the user inputting their id number and the form outputs their name into another textbox (textBox1).

When I use either the string 'input' or textBox4.Text itself I get an error message which is: "Fatal error encountered during command execution."

However if I manually type in a correct id number in the code itself it returns the correct vaule

New to C# and mysql sorry for any big errors.

Comment: It looks like are you trying to do this with a parameter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/652978/62576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, actually. You're using a parameter (`@input`) and **not** concatenating strings (`"select .. " + text + " from ..."`), which is wrong for many reasons.

Just tell your command how to replace that parameter. I guess it's something like this (not sure for MySQL):

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@input", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
```

Note that I'm assuming that `Id` is of type `SqlDbType.Int`. You may change it accordingly.

You must do this **before** calling `myCommand.ExecuteReader()`. Most likely, you'll put this line after `myCommand.CommandText = "...";`.

Comment: Andre - you should also tell the user where this line goes; basically after the `myCommand.CommandText = ...` and before the `ExecuteReader`. They're new to all this so they may not make the connection.

Comment: Plus one since you got your answer in while I was typing mine :P

Comment: @Brian Thanks! I'm usually the slower one =)

Comment: Thanks very much Andre + Ed it now works! after a few hours of trying -.- I was looking around and saw parts of your solution dotted about, tried them all individually and got even more errors so I thought I was going in the wrong direction.

Comment: @user2509919 You're welcome, I'm glad to help. Let us know if you have any further doubt regarding this question and don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I would do in your case:

```
string connString = "SERVER=;UID=;PASSWORD=;DATABASE=;";
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connString);
MySqlCommand myCommand = connect.CreateCommand();
string input = textBox4.Text;

myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM project WHERE Id = @input";
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@input", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
connect.Open();

MySqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
   textBox1.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();

connect.Close();
```

As you can see in the example above I am doing two things:

1. Sanitizing the input by using a [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) and,
2. Converting the value of "@input" to a number; which is the assumption based on your question.

Best of luck to you, and please continue learning!