# Getting Data Between Two Dates From MySql in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime-format

I want to get data between two dates.I am using a MySql database with my C# winforms. At the time of inserting the dates I converted the date to `dd-MM-yyyy` and saved these dates in the database having column of type varchar. Now I want to fetch results between two dates here is my code:

```
string dateFrom = dtp_dfrom.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
string dateTo = dtp_dto.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

//MessageBox.Show(dateFrom+" "+dateTo);

conn = new MySqlConnection(myconstring);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT trans_date, product_type AS Item, product_quantity, amount, SUM( product_quantity ) AS Qty, SUM( amount ) AS 'Total Price' FROM main_table WHERE trans_date BETWEEN '"+dateFrom+"' AND  '"+dateTo+"' GROUP BY product_type", conn);
sda.Fill(dt);
```

Now the problem is I am not getting the date as required.Anybody can help me out. I am very new to dates formats. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "saved these dates in the database having column of type varchar" -- why would you do that? The DATE/DATETIME datatypes are there for a reason. Also, creating an sql statement like that is very bad. Please use parameterized queries as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp) for example.

Comment: Use query Date dataypes and please, for god sake, USE PARAMETERS. @Soner Gönül is absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I converted the date to dd-MM-yyyy and saved these dates in the
> database having column of type **varchar**

No offense but this is terribly wrong. There is no reason to use `varchar` as column type for your date values. Use `DATE` or `DATETIME` column types instead. That's what they for.

- [MySQL Data Types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm)

In your case, I suggest you to use `DATE` column type because it supports `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

And you should always use *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*. This kind of string manipulations are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

```
string dateFrom = dtp_dfrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string dateTo = dtp_dto.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");   

using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myconstring))
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT trans_date, product_type AS Item, product_quantity, amount, SUM( product_quantity ) AS Qty, SUM( amount ) AS 'Total Price' FROM main_table WHERE trans_date BETWEEN @dateFrom AND  @dateTo GROUP BY product_type"))
   {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", dateFrom);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", dateTo);
      MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
      sda.Fill(dt);
   }
}
```

Comment: I have changed the column type to DATE as suggested and now i have the following exception : Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a between on a varchar column, you have to cast it to datetime/date first.

Like the following:

```
cast(trans_date as date) BETWEEN '"+dateFrom+"' AND  '"+dateTo+"'
```

Though there is no reason why you are saving a date value into a varchar column, you should modify the table and use the correct columntype so you don't need to cast.

Btw, you should use parameters instead of string manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for **[STR_TO_DATE](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php)**

```
string dateFrom = dtp_dfrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
string dateTo = dtp_dto.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT trans_date, product_type AS Item, product_quantity, amount, SUM( product_quantity ) AS Qty, SUM( amount ) AS 'Total Price' FROM main_table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(trans_date,''%d-%m-%Y'') BETWEEN '"+dateFrom+"' AND  '"+dateTo+"' GROUP BY product_type", conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `BETWEEN` with `varchar` data, you'll have to use `datetime/date` as the column type.

It would also be better to use parameters with your query like so:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT trans_date, product_type AS Item, product_quantity, amount, SUM( product_quantity ) AS Qty, SUM( amount ) AS 'Total Price' FROM main_table WHERE trans_date BETWEEN @from AND @to GROUP BY product_type", conn);

try
{
    SqlParameter param;
    param = new MySqlParameter("@from", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
    param.Value = dateFrom ;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    param = new MySqlParameter("@to", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
    param.Value = dateTo;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sda.Fill(dt);
}
finally
{
    cmd.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but I stored date using **DateTime** as data type.

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=abc;Integrated Security=true;");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select p.POID,p.SupplierID,p.SupplierDesc, p.CreateDate,  p.PaymentDetails,p.Status,q.Quantity,q.BalQty,q.PartNo from PoToSupplierMaster p inner join PoToSupplierMasterItems q on p.POID=q.SNO where q.PartNo='" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text + "' and   p.CreateDate between '" + TextBox1.Text + "' and '" + TextBox2.Text + "'", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView2.DataSource = ds;
    GridView2.DataBind();
```

in my case I used gridview. but its working fine.