# Saving and screenshot [image] to a database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to save a image directory that a user opened into a database. But the symbol "\" is not in the path. It is turning out like **C:UsersAshleyDesktopScreenshot_1.png** and as you can see it has no `\`, which make it an invalid path.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(open.FileName);
            pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(open.FileName);
            MySQL.ExecuteNonQuery(@"UPDATE users SET profile_image_dir = '" + open.FileName + "' WHERE username = '" + User.Details.Username + "'");
            MessageBox.Show(""+ open.FileName + "\r\n");
        }
```

On the MySQL.ExecuteNonQuery i am saving it to the database and it is turning out like as i showed before

Comment: +1 for parameterized queries. But still I think you can just `open.File.Replace("\", "\\");` right before `MySQL.ExecuteNonQuery`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A parameterized query should work

```
string cmdText = @"UPDATE users SET profile_image_dir = @file
                   WHERE username = @uname";

using(MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(.....))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cn))
{
   cn.Open();
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", open.FileName);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", User.Details.Username);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp). Doing so is safer and will help avoid other potential problems.

That being said, you can also look at the [MySql documentation on string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html) and you'll see how it handles a backslash to see what it's doing with your literal string.