# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax - but SQL statement works

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am trying to iteratively update a MySql table in my c# app in a for loop. I am getting this error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '935 WHERE ID=1' at line 1
```

However, when I run my SQL statement in PhpMyAdmin, it is working well and it updates particular place in my table.

CODE:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            string queryMean = " SELECT (RT1+RT2+RT3+RT4+RT5+RT6+RT7+RT8+RT9+RT10+RT11+RT12+RT13+RT14+RT15+RT16+RT17+RT18+RT19+RT20+RT21+RT22+RT23+RT24+RT25+RT26+RT27+RT28+RT29+RT30+RT31+RT32+RT33+RT34+RT35+RT36+RT37+RT38+RT39+RT40+RT41+RT42+RT43+RT44+RT45+RT46+RT47+RT48+RT49+RT50+RT51+RT52+RT53+RT54+RT55+RT56+RT57+RT58+RT59+RT60+RT61+RT62+RT63+RT64+RT65+RT66+RT67+RT68+RT69+RT70+RT71+RT72+RT73+RT74+RT75+RT76+RT77)/77 AS priem FROM reflextime WHERE reflextime.ID=" + i;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryMean, conect);

            readerMean = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            readerMean.Read();
            string result = readerMean["priem"].ToString();
            double priem = Convert.ToDouble(result);
            double priemer = Math.Round(priem, 3);
            readerMean.Close();

            string query2 = "UPDATE feture SET priemer="+priemer+" WHERE ID="+i;
            MySqlCommand cmdx = new MySqlCommand(query2, conect);
            cmdx.ExecuteScalar();   // here is the exception thrown
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is `priemer` column type is character? And please use parameterized queries. This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: First thing to do: start using parameterized SQL instead of including values in the SQL directly. Aside from anything else, your code is currently culture-sensitive.

Comment: which one of the two queries actually fails? I guess the update? Could you please print out the queries you get when they fail?

Comment: How on earth do you end up with 77 columns all, apparently, containing compatible/comparable values, and not start to think that there must be a better way to model this?

Comment: What is the query who fails? You could isolate one of them to the problem. And as It said up use parametrized Sql.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know that this is not a pretty solution at all, but I did not find any other way to compute mean of values from all columns WHERE ID = something. If you are aware of something, Please let me know and I will be very thankful

Comment: Almost always, what it means is that instead of having columns `ID, RT1, RT2, RT3`, etc, what you ought to have are just the columns `ID,x,RT` where `x` is the column that will contain `1`, `2`, `3`, etc, and given a suitable name. Essentially, it looks like you've ended up with *data* embedded in your table's *metadata*. Computing the average for 77 *rows* values for a single column is a built-in operator, `AVG(RT)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that if this runs on your machine (slovak culture settings) that the value in `double priemer` gets translated to string as e.g. "586,935". That is not what you want, as `,` has different meaning in SQL than `.`. 
Simplest way to fix the problem is to use

```
string query2 = "UPDATE feture SET priemer="+priemer.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)+" WHERE ID="+i;
```

You may have found this issue, if you printed the query2 before posting it here, by the way.

Be also aware that this is in no way a best practice to call a query in C#, a nice clue for how to create a parametrised query may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp).

Comment: If you aren't going to provide a solution that uses SQL parameters you should at least mention that building SQL queries in this way is a very bad idea.

Comment: OK, I'll mention it, but it was already mentioned in the comments - I didn't want to copy what someone else has already said.

Comment: Many people don't bother to read the comments and instead look straight at the answers.