# Listing matching items in a combo box while entering a text?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, mvp

I have a `ComboBox` in a form and while the user typing some text in the box, if there are matching items in the database with the text typed, should be listed in the `ComboBox`. So that the user can be notified if the item being entered is already in the database. I'm trying to achieve this as follows.

When a text is entered in the `combo` it will fire an event. Listening to that event, `Presenter` will get matching user list from the database and then the list will be set as the `DataSource` of the `ComboBox` as follows...

But why it is not displayed in the combo? Please let me know the issue in this code!

Form

```
public partial class frmUser : Form
{
    // two seperate get and set properties are used to same combo box as a list will be set as the datasource.

    public string UserName 
    {
        get{return cmbUserName.Text;}
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> UserList
    {
        set { cmbUserName.DataSource = value; }
    }
    private void cmbUserName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnChangeText(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Presenter

```
class UserPresenter
{       
    private void WireUpEvents()
    {
        _View.OnChangeText += new EventHandler(_View_OnChangeText);
    }

    private void _View_OnChangeText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowMatchingUsers();
    }

    private void ShowMatchingUsers()
    {
        var userList = _DataService.GetUsers(_View.UserName ); //edit
        _Veiew.UserList = userList; //edit
    }
}
```

DataService

```
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(string userID)
    { 
        string selectStatement = "SELECT user_id from [user] WHERE user_id like '@userID %'";
        List<User> UserList = new List<User>();

        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(db.ConnectionString))

        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@userID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userID ;
            sqlConnection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())

                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    UserList.Add(
                    new User 
                    {
                        UserID = (string) dataReader["user_id"]
                    });
                }

            return UserList;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I did this in WPF with get / set and INPC.  What I found was even for 20,000 items it was worth downloading all up front and using LINQ.  Tab to get the first matching is also a nice feature.  If you want to get into some more advanced and more responsive UI then I recommend WPF and MVVM.

Comment: _the list will be set as the DataSource of the ComboBox_ : I don't see where that part is happening. Looks like the returning result set is thrown away.. But maybe I am missing something in your code..??

Comment: @TaW, Actually I was referring to this property in the view -> public IEnumerable<User> UserList
    {
        set { cmbUserName.DataSource = value; }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have given the value to the parameter as `userID+"%"` instead of `userID`. With regard to user listing, I think I have to have a loop adding items to the list somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you **exactly** how to change your code because I am missing quite a few details, like some events and classes and the possible nesting states of your classes and objects.

But the error is, like I noted, the fact that the resulting `IEnumerable<User>`which `GetUsers` brings back is thrown away.

You wrote that it **should** get used as the `DataSource` of the `ComboBox` via the `Property UserList` but in fact you are **hiding** this property by declaring a new

```
List<User> UserList = new List<User>();
```

locally in `GetUsers`. This would be OK, albeit a little confusing; (I suggest you call it something different like `newUserlist` ;) but you still need to set the real `UserList` to the returned result set somewhere!

When I patched this up like this (missing important info on your actual code)

```
private void cmbUserName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  UserList = _DataService.GetUsers("_View.UserName");

   ///OnChangeText(sender, e); re-instate your own wiring!
}
```

a dummy value showed up fine in the Combobox..

You should not use my code but stay with you set up! Changing

```
_DataService.GetUsers(_View.UserName );
```

to

```
Userlist = _DataService.GetUsers(_View.UserName );
```

seems to be the direct solution, but you probably will have to watch for a way to connect innner and outer class variables..

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I found an issue in my sql LIKE. when hard coded its working but when parameter is used its not. In my code there  is an space between @userID and %. Even it is removed its not giving the desired output?

Comment: You need to use a parameter: `MySqlCommand cmd = oldDb.GetSqlStringCommand(CommandType.Text,"SELECT * _
FROM users WHERE name LIKE @searchText");
MySqlParameter nameParameter= cmd.CreateParameter();
nameParameter.DbType = DbType.String;
nameParameter.ParameterName = "@searchText"
nameParameter.Value = "%John%";`  taken from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/542184/MySqlCommand-MySqlParameter-and-LIKE-with-Percent) or look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks now its ok. I should have given the value to the parameter as `userID+"%"` instead of `userID`. Now I have a problem with listing. The user list is not shown in list. I think I have to have a loop adding items to the list somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

use visual studio, set combobox property as follows
 combobox *autocompletemode* = **SuggestAppend** & *autocompletesource*=**ListItems**