# SQL Syntax Error

Tags: c#, mysql

when I try to insert data using form it throws the exception(e1) "Error Occured Please Try Again" you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your Mysql server version for the right syntax to use near " at line1
Please help to correct this error

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.Append("Insert Into my_project_data.vehicle(ChassyNumber ,ManufacturedYear, EngineCapacity,Price,Features ,VehicleBrand , VehicleType) Values('" + chassy_txt.Text + "','"+manufac_year_txt.Text+"','"+Engine_Capasity_txt.Text+"','"+Price_txt.Text+"','"+Features_rich_txt.Text+"',");

Classes.DB_Connectivity db = new Classes.DB_Connectivity();

try
{
    db.openConnection();

        if ((radioButton1.Checked || radioButton2.Checked) && (radioButton7.Checked || radioButton11.Checked) && ( manufac_year_txt.Text != "" && Engine_Capasity_txt.Text != "" && Price_txt.Text != "" && Features_rich_txt.Text != ""))
        {


            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                query.Append("BMW ,");

            }
            if (radioButton2.Checked) 
            {
                query.Append("Benz , ");
            }
            if (radioButton7.Checked)
            {
                query.Append("Car ,");
            }
            if (radioButton11.Checked)
            {
                query.Append("SUV ,");
            }

           if ( manufac_year_txt.Text != "" && Engine_Capasity_txt.Text != "" && Price_txt.Text != "" && Features_rich_txt.Text != "")
           { 
               query.Append(" '"+manufac_year_txt.Text+"', '"+Engine_Capasity_txt.Text+"','"+Price_txt.Text+"','"+Features_rich_txt.Text+"'");
            }

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query.ToString(), db.conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            MessageBox.Show(" Vehicle Registration Successfull ", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fill All Required Information ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

}
catch (Exception e1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error Occured Please Try Again "  +e1.Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to build queries. They are prone to SQL Injection. For debug purpose, copy the generated query string from your C# code and try to execute it on mysql directly , see what is the error you get

Comment: You've spelt chassis wrong?

Comment: Spurious end comma i think "',"

Comment: Print the SQL command you're about to execute in order to debug.

Comment: I simply do not understand how *anyone* writing SQL in 2014 thinks that concatenating input is *ever* sensible, reasonable, or acceptable...

Comment: This looks **terrifyingly** insecure. Are you sure you're [properly escaping that data](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html)? Using placeholders avoids having to be concerned about this.

Comment: when i execute this in mysql directly it works fine so what is the secured way and how to use it?

Comment: [A classic on Sql Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and an example of [Parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp)

Comment: I replaced radio buttons with combo boxes so now it works fine but i want to know how to correct this error. I am just a beginner so it doesn't matter whether it is 2014 or 2020 everyone has to start first so this is my starting point so please anyone can show me what is the secured and  correct way to do it

Comment: Everyone was a beginner once. But beginning now one can begin at a better starting point than beginning in say 2000. Please have a look at the accepted answer of the second link which [Steve gave you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp) to see a parameterized query in action.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed an apostrophe here in the end of the line(added it in bold):

> query.Append("Insert Into my_project_data.vehicle(ChassyNumber
>   ,ManufacturedYear, EngineCapacity,Price,Features ,VehicleBrand ,
>   VehicleType) Values('" + chassy_txt.Text +
>   "','"+manufac_year_txt.Text+"','"+Engine_Capasity_txt.Text+"','"+Price_txt.Text+"','"+Features_rich_txt.Text+"',");

Should be '"+Features_rich_txt.Text+"',**'**");
and you have:
'"+Features_rich_txt.Text+"',");

Also you need an apostrophe after the car model:
like:
query.Append("BMW ',");
and so on.

Please also consider one of the comments above regarding the SQL injection.

Comment: It didn't work   query.Append("Insert..........................               '"+Features_rich_txt.Text+"',"); this final " is used to close the insert statement

Comment: Well, your VehicleBrand field value must be between apostrophes as far as understood. It is not, you have to fix it.

Comment: And yes, it is pretty easy to ruin whole your database, get your clients private data etc using this code. Consider, for example (please don't try it!) that somebody will put value  _','','','','','',''); delete from my_project_data.vehicle;_ to the  textbox chassy_txt?