# c# stripping characters from string when submitting to database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio

I am currently working on a project where I need to submit a file path to a database, and be able to pull that path from the database as well.

Currently I am able to submit the path to the database and pull the data from the database, however the slashes in the path seem to be getting stripped from the string when I submit to the database.

**How can I stop the \ from being stripped when submitting to the database and when pulling from the database?**

Here is my save button event code:

```
private void btnSaveSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=username;password=password";
    string Query = "insert into ephex_contcollections.Paths (toindex,indexed) values('" + this.txtToIndexPath.Text + "','" + this.txtIndexedPath.Text + "') ;";
    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

    MySqlCommand cmdDB = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConn);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        myConn.Open();
        myReader = cmdDB.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Save Successful");

        while (myReader.Read())
        {

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
} //close save button event
```

**The string that I am submitting to the database look like this while in the text box:**

C:\Users\Meta\Desktop\Alpha

**But they submit to the database like this:**

C:UsersMetaDesktopAlpha

Thanks in advance *(I am new to using MySQL databases with C# and am rusty on my C# as well)*.

Comment: You should construct a parameterized query instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Queue SQL Injection discussion.  Parameterize your statements.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp

Comment: use parameters instead of the textbox text in the query

Comment: '\' is the escape character in c#. I am not sure how it functions with concatenating strings, but if you were to hardcode Query to insert a single record, the \ character would need to escape itself. For instance:  string Query = "insert into ephex_contcollections.Paths (toindex,indexed) values ('Home','C:\\Users\\Home')"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [SQL Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but if you want to solve this quick and dirty, add double slashes to the path so the output will be: `C:\\Users\\Meta\\Desktop\\Alpha`

```
string Query = "insert into ephex_contcollections.Paths (toindex,indexed) values('" + this.txtToIndexPath.Text.Replace(@"\" , @"\\") + "','" + this.txtIndexedPath.Text.Replace(@"\" , @"\\") + "') ;";
```

Comment: Thanks! I have adapted this in several places (submitting and pulling data), the program I am working on is for the office i work at and only 3 people (the CEO, COO, and myself) will have access to the program so I should be good using this method.

Comment: Use Sql Parameters no matter who is accessing your application.  What if the CEO has a buddy who knows security and he tests your application to see if it is vulnerble to Sql Injection.

Comment: Always use Sql Parameters. Always.  Not doing this as a matter of practice will lead to you not doing it when it matters more.  Develop good habits now, not after the breach...

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that using a slash, even within a string, means something.

You need to use the special character for backslash within your string like this

"hello \\ world" = "hello \ world"

also, you can use the @ symbol in front of the string to not use escape characters, but i dont recommend it, like this string s = @ "hello \ world" = " hello \ world".

Hope that helps.

edit : stackoverflow keeps editing my backslashes out