# Incorrect integer value : 'System.Windows.Forms.Textbox, Text: 1' for column 'customer_id' at row 1

Tags: c#, database

I don't know why I am getting this error. I did insert integer values before. In Form1, I inserted both strings and int values before in previous forms.

```
        string customer_id = variables.cid;
        customerID_txt.Text = customer_id;

        string constring2 = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        string Query2 = "insert into artgallery.orders(customer_id,painting_id) values ('" + this.customerID_txt + "','" + this.pID_txt.Text + "');";
        MySqlConnection conDatabase2 = new MySqlConnection(constring2);
```

And the `variables.cid` is a string.

Comment: your table column customer_id,painting_id are INT or varchar?

Comment: It looks like you are passing the customer_ID as string instead of as an integer.

Comment: Please use parametrized queries to avoid this particular issue and generic [bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) answers.

Comment: Both customer_id and painting_id are INT in my orders table.BUT How do i pass it as INT ? How do i convert customerID_txt.Text to int?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp... Hopefully someone familiar with MySQL will provide proper parametrized query as answer instead of fixing up string concatenation issues you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the quotes from the value:

```
string customer_id = variables.cid;
customerID_txt.Text = customer_id;

string constring2 = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
string Query2 = "insert into artgallery.orders(customer_id,painting_id) values (" + this.customerID_txt + ",'" + this.pID_txt.Text + "');";
MySqlConnection conDatabase2 = new MySqlConnection(constring2);
```

And if `this.customer_id` is a text box you will need to change it to `this.customer_id.Text` like you did with `this.pID_txt.Text`

Answer (score 0):

You mean this instead: (note the `.Text` and removing the quotes)

```
string customer_id = variables.cid;
customerID_txt.Text = customer_id;

string constring2 = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
string Query2 = "insert into artgallery.orders(customer_id,painting_id) values (" + this.customerID_txt.Text + "," + this.pID_txt.Text + ");";
MySqlConnection conDatabase2 = new MySqlConnection(constring2);
```

Also you probably want to ensure those are integers so that no one can inject code into the database:

```
string customer_id = variables.cid;
customerID_txt.Text = customer_id;

string constring2 = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
string Query2 = "insert into artgallery.orders(customer_id,painting_id) values (" + int.Parse(this.customerID_txt.Text) + "," + int.Parse(this.pID_txt.Text) + ");";
MySqlConnection conDatabase2 = new MySqlConnection(constring2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quotes and use `customer_id` or `customerID_txt.Text` instead of `customerID_txt` because it's a component. Try this code:

```
string customer_id = variables.cid;
customerID_txt.Text = customer_id;

string constring2 = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
string Query2 = "insert into artgallery.orders(customer_id,painting_id) values (" + customer_id + ",'" + this.pID_txt.Text + "');";
MySqlConnection conDatabase2 = new MySqlConnection(constring2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
string Query2 = "insert into artgallery.orders(customer_id,painting_id) values ('" + this.customerID_txt + "','" + this.pID_txt.Text + "');";
```

creates the following sql:

```
insert into artgallery.orders(customer_id,painting_id) values ('xxx','yyy');
```

That SQL says that you are trying to insert two strings. Remove the quotes and you'll be on your way (assuming that the value is indeed an integer, etc.). As was noted, you want to do parametrized SQL to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, it's strongly recommended to use parameterized query.
The code should be on the lines of (assuming both parameters are int):

```
string customer_id = variables.cid;
customerID_txt.Text = customer_id;
string constring2 = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";

using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(constring2))
{
    string query = "insert into artgallery.orders(customer_id, painting_id) values (@cutsomerId, @paintingId);";

    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

    command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("customerId", int.Parse(this.customerID_txt.Text)));
    command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("paintingId", int.Parse(this.pID_txt.Text)));

    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```