# Name of Table as a Variabe in SQL (C# parameter)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, parameters

I have a difficult SQL query, and I don't want to rewrite it on Linq. The problem is: I have two equal tables and I must use one of them in depending on the some condition. So, to pass parameter (the name of table) I use this:

```
List<Variables> lst = db.Database
    .SqlQuery<Variables>(s, new SqlParameter("tableSource", sourceTable))
    .ToList();
```

And My query like this:

```
SELECT @tableSource.PlanId,
   @tableSource.PlanSmall AS PlanImg,
   @tableSource.NOb,
...
```

It Doesn't works, could someone help me, please?

Comment: What is `s`...?

Comment: Please don't do this, you'll only have problems. Instead use your ORM properly otherwise you're opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: If you have two tables with identical structures, it's usually an indication that your data modelling has gone wrong. Often, you'll find that some piece of *data* has instead been placed in the *metadata*, specifically in the names of the tables. If you can correct it (back to a single table with one or more additional columns to contain the misplaced data) you'll find *many* queries fall out far more naturally rather than trying to parameterize the table name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL table name as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254721/mysql-table-name-as-parameter)

Comment: I need not injection, you exaggerate, I don't pass name of table through get or post.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `SqlParameter` for this. It is meant to be used to set values for parameters in `WHERE` clauses for instance. You may consider using a construct like

```
if (someParam.Equals("thisValue")
{
  return "SELECT * FROM thisTable";
} else if (someParam.Equals("thatValue")
{ 
  return "SELECT * FROM thatTable"; 
}
```

Comment: It is not flexibly, I want to use parameter.