# C# SQL parameterized SQL Query

Tags: c#, mysql

I just keep on getting Syntax error when I used parameterized sql query.

```
public List<string> Cat(string product,string table)
{
    List<string> Products = new List<string>();
    Global global = new Global();
    string sql = "SELECT @prod FROM @tbl";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(global.ConnectionString);
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod", product);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbl", table);
    connection.Open();
    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            Products.Add(reader.GetString("@prod"));
    }
    connection.Close();
    return Products;
}

public List<string> CallProducts(string category)
{
    string table;
    string product;
    List<string> stacks = new List<string>();
    if (category == "Accessories")
    {
        product = "Accessories_Name";
        table = "tbl_accessories";
        stacks.AddRange(Cat(product, table).ToArray());                
    }
    else if (category == "Batteries")
    {
        table = "tbl_batteries";
    }
    else if (category == "Cotton")
    {
        table = "tbl_cotton";
    }
    else if (category == "Juices")
    {
        table = "tbl_juices";
    }
    else if (category == "Kits")
    {
        table = "tbl_kits";
    }
    else if (category == "Mods")
    {
        table = "tbl_mods";
    }
    else
    {
        table = "tbl_vapeset";
    }
    return stacks;
}
```

I just keep on getting SQL Syntax Error. It works if the table and the name is manually inputted rather than using parameters.

Hoping you can help.

Need for a project.

Thanks!

Comment: **Pro Tip** we cant see your screen, so copying the errors in is mandatory

Comment: Also `public  List<string> Cat(string product, string table)`

Comment: Hi Pro Tip,You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tbl_accessories'' at line 1.

Comment: This is the error i get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL table name as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254721/mysql-table-name-as-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Correct use would be:

```
string sql = $"SELECT {product} FROM {table}";
```

Because table and column are not parameters.

Moreover, I would recommend using `Command.Parameters.Add(...).Value(...)`,
over `Parameters.AddWithValue`, since in first approach you can explicitly decide what datatype you want to pass and prevent SQL from guessing it.

Comment: Hi, I tried using this but also gives the same error.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '} FROM {table}' at line 1

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip :) it was such a big help :) we got it now

Comment: If answer helped you, you should accept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote it.