# How to Update paragraph from mysql table using c#

Tags: c#

I tried to update a paragraph from mysql table,but i got error like this

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 's first-ever super-villainess."

My mysql Query

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE `moviemaster` SET  `Runtime`='" + runtime + "',`DateMasterId`='" + dateid + "',`Trailer`='" + trailer + "',`Synopsis`='" + synopsis + "' WHERE `MovieMasterId`='" + movieid + "'";
```

I  got error in 'synopsis',it's a big data containing a large paragraph.If i romove 'Synopsis' section from the query,everything working fine.What exactly the problem.How can i resolve this?

Comment: What is the `synopsis` variable _exactly_? `MovieMasterId` seems like a numerical column as well. If so, you don't need single quotes with it. You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And parameterized statements handle the escape characters as well.

Comment: @SonerGönül:its a content of movie synopsis.

Comment: Just a side-node: please use parameters instead string-concatenation otherwise your code is potentially open for SQL-Injection.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan.S No, I mean it's _real_ value that it contains. The value when you see on debugger.

Comment: You probably have some sort of character in the paragraph that ends the statement such as a '`'. Using parametrized queries will fix that issue. Add a line break to the update statement and check to see what query is being passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please avoid using inline query. Your database can be subjected to SQL Injection. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748357/125740), on what can be done using SQL Injection.

And use paramterized query instead. Here is the example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/652999/125740). This way, even if your string has special characters, it will not break and let you insert/update/select based on parameters.

```
private String readCommand = "SELECT LEVEL FROM USERS WHERE VAL_1 = @param_val_1 AND VAL_2 = @param_val_2;";
public bool read(string id)
{
    level = -1;
    MySqlCommand m = new MySqlCommand(readCommand);
    m.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_val_1", val1);
    m.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_val_2", val2);
    level = Convert.ToInt32(m.ExecuteScalar());
    return true;
}
```

and finally, your query will become

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE `moviemaster` SET  `Runtime`= @param1,`DateMasterId`= @dateid, `Trailer`= @trailer,`Synopsis`= @synopsis WHERE `MovieMasterId`= @movieid";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", runtime);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateid", dateid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trailer", trailer);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@synopsis", synopsis);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movieid", movieid);
```

Answer (score 1):

> @SonerGönül:Ok,fine.. then please show me an example of parameterised
>   query

Sure. I also wanna add a few best practice as well.

- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically.
- You don't need to escape every column with `` characters. You should *only* escape if they are [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) for your db provider. Of course, at the end, changing them to *non-reserved* words is better.
- Do not use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate upexpected and surprising result sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your [parameter type](http://underpop.online.fr/m/mysql/manual/mysql-connectors-apis-connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldbtype.html) and it's size.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
     cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE moviemaster 
                         SET Runtime = @runtime, DateMasterId = @dateid, Trailer = @trailer, Synopsis = @synopsis
                         WHERE MovieMasterId = @movieid";
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@runtime", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = runtime; ;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dateid;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@trailer", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = trailer;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@synopsis", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = synopsis;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@movieid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = movieid;
     // I assumed your column types are VarChar.
     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @SonerGönül I up voted this answer since I myself have had bad experience with weird down votes.  And in any case this was a useful answer

Comment: @chrisl08 Thanks. I just didn't figure out anything wrong about my answer.