# Mysql Error- Data retrieval

Tags: mysql

What is wrong in the following code? I am trying to retrieve data from the datbase, and this error is shows. kindly provide a solution.
Error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wrap' at line 1 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Line 19:         da.SelectCommand = cmd;
Line 20:         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
Line 21:         da.Fill(ds,"Recipe_Info");
Line 22:         DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Recipe_Info"].Rows[0];
Line 23:         String r_name, r_ing, r_desc, r_ins;
```

Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wrap' at line 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class Detailed_Recipe_View : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       String recipe_name=Session["Recipe_Name"].ToString();
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=FreedomKitchen;Uid=root;Password=;");
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select User_ID,Recipe_Name,All_Ingredients,Recipe_Description,Recipe_Instructions from Recipes where Recipe_Name="+recipe_name, con);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds,"Recipe_Info");
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Recipe_Info"].Rows[0];
        String r_name, r_ing, r_desc, r_ins;

        r_name = Convert.ToString(dr["Recipe_Name"]);
        r_ing = Convert.ToString(dr["All_Ingredients"]);
        r_desc = Convert.ToString(dr["Recipe_Description"]);
        r_ins = Convert.ToString(dr["Recipe_Instructions"]);

        txtRecipeName.Text = r_name;
        txtDescription.Text = r_desc;
        txtAllIngredients.Text = r_ing;
        txtInstructions.Text = r_ins;

    }
}
```

Comment: But it shows line 21 as the error.

Comment: It looks like the problem is here: Recipe_Name="+recipe_name.. check the content of recipe_name variable

Answer (score 0):

You should put single quotes around the `recipe_name` in the `WHERE` condition:

```
new MySqlCommand("select ... from Recipes where Recipe_Name = '" + recipe_name + "'", con);
```

A better alternative would be to use a parameterized query ([Parameterized Query for MySQL with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp)).