# MySQL INSERT syntax error near '' at line 1 visual c#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Im having a hard time solving this error about `MySQL Syntax`.

Here is the `MySQL syntax`

```
try
        {
            SQL = "INSERT INTO payment_history_tbl (id, payment_type, date, time, amount, student_no) VALUES (NULL, '" + cmbbxPaymentType.Text + "', CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME(), '" + txtbxPaymentAmt.Text + "', '" + msktxbxStudNo.Text + "'";
            // INSERT INTO `studentpaymentqueuing`.`payment_history_tbl` (`id`, `payment_type`, `date`, `time`, `amount`, `student_no`) VALUES (NULL, 'Certificate of Enrollment', '2017-02-24', '10:19:28', '60.00', '13-0695');
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQL, conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

Any idea?

Comment: Your code will certainly fail if someone put " or just '. Use SQL parameter to fix it.

Comment: Here's an idea... the code in this question follows a pattern we frequently see in code that vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you miss `)`?

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO payment_history_tbl (id, payment_type, date, time, amount, student_no) VALUES (NULL, '" + cmbbxPaymentType.Text + "', CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME(), '" + msktxbxStudNo.Text + "')";
```

Comment: Oh! my bad -___- I guess I was so used to `SELECT` statement that has no ")" in the end. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I thought MySql is not completely lost and supports parametrized queries (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp), are you sure you are recommending the best practices in the answer?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You are absolutly right, here is just an answer, maybe not recommendable, but answer is answer, if answer is wrong, you can tell me then I'll fix it. If you have some other better answers, then you answer here. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Using String.Format may help you to get pretty code and finding bug easily.
**Example:**

```
String query = String.Empty;
query += String.Format("INSERT INTO payment_history_tbl (id, payment_type, date, time, amount, student_no)");
query += String.Format(" VALUES (NULL, '{0}', '{1}', {2}, '{3}', '{4}');", cmbbxPaymentType.Text, CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME(), txtbxPaymentAmt.Text, msktxbxStudNo.Text);
```