# c# sql date return without time

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

Hi I am trying to get the date from a sql table however whenever I get it, it returns with the time. Even though in the database table it does not have a time.

```
        con.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select I_InvoiceNo, I_Date from tblOrdInvoice where O_OrderNo = '" + orderNoTxt.Text + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OdbcDataAdapter sda = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            invoiceNoTxt.Text = dr["I_InvoiceNo"].ToString();
            invoiceDateTxt.Text = dr["I_Date"].ToString();
        }
```

The date is being returned as "27/03/2017 00:00:00" . I only want the date. Any Help please.

Comment: It is a datetime for net. Convert to DateTime, then ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: Caution, your query is wide open to SQL Injection.

Comment: What is the format of column I_Date ?

Comment: ^how? and what can i do?

Comment: @ZeeSoft For preventing SQL injection, used parameterized queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp

Comment: You don't need to convert anything, there's nothing wrong with the result. DateTime is a *binary* value. If you want to format it in a certain way, specify it as an argument to `ToString()`, eg `ToString("d")` or `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
string dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
invoiceDateTxt.Text = dr.Field<DateTime>("I_Date").ToString(dateFormat);
```

Change your `dateFormat` variable to whatever format you like.

Comment: when i try for another function i get an error.                         orderDateTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0]["O_OrderDate"].ToString();

Comment: @ZeeSoft Try this: `dt.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("I_Date").ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert DateTime to whichever format you want from code side.
For example by using :

```
invoiceDateTxt.Text = dr["I_Date"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Or if you want to fetch only date part from mysql , then you can use something like below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112) 'Date Part Only'

RESULT:
Date Part Only
--------------
20170327
Example 2:

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111) 'Date Part Only'

RESULT:
Date Part Only
--------------
2017/03/27
```

For more details visit this [link](http://sqlhints.com/2013/07/14/how-to-get-date-part-only-from-datetime-in-sql-server/).

Comment: String formatting on the server side is typically a bug. The server has no idea about the client's locale.