# Incorrect date value: for column 'Date' at row 1?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have created a rest web api using Asp.net. When I tried to insert data to my table using post, I'm getting this exception: Incorrect date value: '07/11/2017 12:00:00 AM' for column 'Date' at row 1. What is the correct date value to insert to Mysql database?

```
public long addmeterreadingrecord(meterreadingrecords meterreadingrecord )
{
  MySqlConnection myconn = getDBConn();
  String sqlstr = 
  "INSERT INTO meterreadingrecords (ID,Date,User,ImageLink,ActualMeterReadingID) VALUES ('" 
          + meterreadingrecord.Id + "','" + meterreadingrecord.Date + "','" 
          + meterreadingrecord.User + "','" + meterreadingrecord.Imagelink+"','"
          + meterreadingrecord.ActualmeterreadingId+"')";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlstr, myconn);
        myconn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myconn.Close();
        myconn.Dispose();
        long id = cmd.LastInsertedId;
        return id;
    }
```

How I inserted data using a rest client.

```
{
"ID" : "zzz",
"Date": "11/07/2017",
"User" : "Me",
"ImageLink" : "testimg",
"ActualMeterReadingID" : "ccc"
}
```

Data type for date in mysql db is Date. Not DateTime.

Comment: Please avoid samples demonstrating SQL injection - as it may cause negative reaction to post neglecting good practices. [Edit] post to use parametrized queries as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL expects a four digit year followed by a two-digit month and a two-digit day.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) Yesterday's date (Jul. 9) is:

```
'2017-07-09'
```

MySQL does make some allowances for alternate format (including accepting a `:` as delimiter), but it still expects the format to be year-month-date. The value `11/07/2017` cannot be a correct date by this standard. In order to account for this, you'll want to use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

```
STR_TO_DATE('11/07/2017', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Also, for reference, [this is a list of valid date string `%` variables.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: I tried as you said. But getting this exception now Truncated incorrect date value: '11/07/2017 12:00:00 AM' 

String sqlstr = "INSERT INTO meterreadingrecords (ID,Date,User,ImageLink,ActualMeterReadingID) VALUES ('" + meterreadingrecord.Id + "',STR_TO_DATE('" + meterreadingrecord.Date + "', '%d/%m/%Y'),'" + meterreadingrecord.User + "','"+meterreadingrecord.Imagelink+"','"+meterreadingrecord.ActualmeterreadingId+"')";

Comment: Have you tried `%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s`? You might need to play with the formatting a little to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

> MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format

[The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)