# Find query from alphanumaric values

Tags: c#, mysql

Intern id is an alphanumeric value.

The question is after run the program the search code only works numbers. not for Alphanumeric. How do i solve this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtsearch.Text != "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please type intern number");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                string SelectQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM interndetails WHERE internnumber =" + Convert.ToString(txtsearch.Text);
                cmd4 = new MySqlCommand(SelectQuery2, con);
                mdr2 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
                if (mdr2.Read())
                {
                    textBox11.Text = mdr2.GetString("name");
                    textBox9.Text = mdr2.GetString("idnumber");
                    textBox6.Text = mdr2.GetString("status");
                    textBox12.Text = mdr2.GetString("statusdate");
                    textBox13.Text = mdr2.GetString("intakedate");
                    textBox14.Text = mdr2.GetString("fplacementdate");
                    textBox10.Text = mdr2.GetString("secbrdpt");
                    textBox15.Text = mdr2.GetString("periodcomplertion");
                    mdr2.Close();
                    con.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No Interns were found!");
                    txtsearch.Clear();
                    txtsearch.Focus();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
                con.Close();
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Use a parameterized query. It will prevent SQL injection too :-)

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is this code not working for Alphanumeric.
Ex = if intern id is 123, this works. but if intern id abcd1234, it does not work

Comment: Is this a valid SQL query?: `SELECT * FROM interndetails WHERE internnumber = abcd1234`? No. Would parameterized queries solve this? Yes. So no, no "but the problem is", parameterized queries are your solution.

Comment: My intern id contains "LK0123" type. so i cannot use integer queries. and please if the parameterized queries are my solution. please direct me to a reference.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp?lq=1)

Comment: Thank you Mr john

Comment: Mr John, could you please help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
string SelectQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM interndetails WHERE internnumber = @internNumber";
cmd4 = new MySqlCommand(SelectQuery2, con);
cmd4.Parameters.Add("@internNumber", MySqlDbType.String).Value = txtsearch.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

might be it help you

SELECT * FROM interndetails WHERE concat(internnumber ,'')= '" + Convert.ToString(txtsearch.Text)+ "'"