# MySqlDataReader Hasn't Row But Query has data

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb, mysqldatareader

My Query in PHPmyadmin has result but in C#, a.read() returns no data.

```
string query = "SELECT answer FROM tbl WHERE level = " + level + " AND subject = '" + subject[i] + "';";

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
connection.Open();
MySqlDataReader a = command.ExecuteReader();
while (a.Read())
{
    //Do Some Things
}
connection.Close();
```

**Edit:**
I've already tried parameterized queries, didn't work, and also tried with the constant values from the table, it doesn't work in the project, but when I run the query in the database it works

Comment: Please debug your code, and share some more info, make your question a [mre]

Comment: And read http://bobby-tables.com before you write any more SQL (in your life, ever) please

Comment: Replace the two variables with the constant values that you have used in PHPMyAdmin and check if now you have the records. If yes then your variables are not what you supposed them to be. After fixing the problem change ASAP this code to a [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Can you show the sql query that brought the data, pls?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parameterized Query for MySQL with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp)

Comment: I've already tried parameterized queries, didn't work, and also tried with the constant values from the table, it doesn't work in the project, but when I run the query in the database it works

Comment: Don't tell me parameterized queries don't work, they do. Show the code that does it, and preferably also some sample data for your table. Please also indicate how you know that `a.Read` returns no data, does it skip the loop, or are you checking the variables in `//Do Some Things`

Comment: use Sql server with ef core and resolve (clean) problem